# How to escape MS-SQL output in html/php?

Tags: php, html, sql-server, htmlspecialchars

Sounds very simple, but I'm kinda confused at the moment.

I have this DB object which includes some values that I want to output in an html form.

Simplified Problem:
`$result` is my db object and this is the html input where I want to output some text which can include double or single quotes.

```
<input class="someclass" name="desc" id="descID" type="text" value="<?=$result['desc'];?>" placeholder="<Description>" />
```

So if `$result['desc']` contains text like this: 'Did you hear about "foobar"?'
everything after the first double quote gets cut off and ends up like this: 'Did you hear about '.

**What i have tried already without success:**

- htmlspecialchars like this `value="<?=htmlspecialchars($result['desc']);?>"` or like this `value="<?=htmlspecialchars($result['desc'], ENT_QUOTES);?>"`
- addslashes

Note: My DB(mssql) saves the string properly. Only have the problems in my html.

I would be glad if you could help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: Just for kicks, have you also tried [htmlspecialentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Comment: `<?php $t = 'Did you hear about "foobar"?'; ?>
<input class="someclass" name="desc" id="descID" type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($t);?>" />` work likes charm!!

Comment: These double quotes around foobar were inserted like this in your DB? If so, escape them before displaying the string.

Comment: ok so i tested those, and the solution of @Parixit seems to work, BUT only if i actually type `<?php $t = 'Did you hear about "foobar"?'; ?>`. i tried `<?php $t = $result['desc']; ?>` and it didn't work

Comment: @EddeAlmeida my DB saves the text literally as Did you hear about "foobar". And your suggestion is exactly what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help so far, but i managed to find a solution to this:

```
<?$descEscaped = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $result['desc']);?>

<input class="someclass" name="desc" id="descID" type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($descEscaped);?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars replaces quotes with "&quot;".

I am using my simple function htmlliteral:

```
function htmlliteral($s){
     return '"'.htmlspecialchars($s).'"';
}
```

With this function you can use:

```
$descEscaped = htmlliteral($result['desc']);
print "<input class=someclass name=desc id=descID type=text value=$descEscaped />";
```